# Struts 2 Arraylist of objects for loop with index

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have an arrayList which has objects of a bean within it. In the view, I am iterating and printing the list using `<c:foreach>` tag.

I am printing this list into a table, so I need to print 4 elements of a list at time inside of a `<tr>` tag. Then the next 4 elements in another `<tr>`, so on.

How would I do that? Is there an index to use so that I can store the value and only start from there the next time I iterate the list?

E.g. of my hypothesis:

```
<for i=list.length i++>
{
   <tr>
       <td>${ListElement}</td>
   </tr>
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you used

Comment: There is no code yet. I am planning the code still

Answer (score 1):

```
 <s:iterator var="listVar" value="%{ListElement}" status="entryStatus">
     <s:property value="#entryStatus.count"/> <!-- start's from 0 -->
     <s:property value="#entryStatus.index"/> <!-- start's from 1 -->
     <s:property value="%{ListElement[#entryStatus.index].yourBeanPropertyName}"/>
     <s:property value="%{#listVar[#entryStatus.index].yourBeanPropertyName}"/>
 </s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<s:iterator>` tag with `begin`, `end` and `status` attributes http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/iterator.html.

Answer (score 0):

I used the  tag along with finding multiples of number of rows. algorithm for code:

```
<c:foreach varStatus=x items=beanObject>
  if(x.index / 4 == 0)
{
  NEW ROW
}

</c:foreach>
```